# Get my own data from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-mvc

Firstly, sorry if it is duplicate question but I really can't find any answer to my problem which is: I'm developing my personal web application where I want show the stream from social networks I am using. One of them is Facebook.

**EDITED**

I want to pull out all my posts from Facebook to my own database. I registered as facebook developer and created a facebook application in order to use Graph API to retrieve necessary data. I set necessary permissions per application and got an access token which i stored in my web app. But after some time this access token becomes invalid. So, as far as I can understand i have to get fresh new access token that to be sure it is valid.

Am I wrong or there is any other solution?

Comment: they must have some api?

Comment: Facebook has API which is called Graph. It has huge documentation but I am looking for concrete implementation for getting data from facebook without submitting the form in order to get access token for necessary data.

Comment: this is no place to get "ready to use" code for free, you should tell us what you tried so far and where exactly you got stuck. there are also countless threads about all the things you are asking already, you just need to use google and stackoverflow.

Comment: Of course access tokens expire. You can extend them to be valid for 60 days, after that you have to get a new one. And how this is done, is described in the docs – so go read them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged the question with Spring MVC, do check out [Spring Social Facebook](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/).  There is a complete section on retrieving a user's profile data that you will find helpful, along with sample code, Spring configuration and useful tips.

Working with Facebook requires creation of an app in Facebook's developer console.  This is also mentioned at the beginning of the Spring Social Facebook documentation but without too much detail.  If you are new to developing with Facebook, you can find documentation on Facebook app development on the [Facebook developer documentation website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).

Comment: `Spring Social Facebook` this is exactly what i'm using in order to get my posts from facebook. What i have read in documentation there is 5 types of `access_token`, but i am interested only in 2 of them: `User Access Token` and `App Access Token`. I do not want to use user access token because user has to interact in order to get it. On this occasion this me because I want to show only mine posts in my web app. On the other hand is it enough to have app access token to get my posts. If so, ho to get/renew it?

Comment: The user access token is an OAuth token and is always valid only for a specified length of time.  Plus, it can be forcibly refreshed as well, for example, if the OAuth server crashes or if there is a breach on the server that leaks the existing tokens.  From a security standpoint, the user must be forced to interact with an OAuth provider so that they are always well informed about an app accessing their information and chances of impersonation or eavesdropping are reduced.